# Still no wxPython for Python 3 (or 3.3) yet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, gui-toolkit

I wanted to start working with wxPython, but I found out that it isn't updated for Python 3. I'm using the newest verion of Python, 3.3 that is.

So I started looking on the web and found some people who said there wasn't, but these threads were like 3 years old.

So my question: Is there still no wxPython update for Python 3? Python 3 has been out for a couple of years now! There should be, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

wxPython 4 is here and supports **Python 2.7** and **3.5**. It can be found on PyPI - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython and is installed via pip:

```
pip install wxPython
```

If you want to try the bleeding edge, there are snapshot builds here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/

You will also want to check out the [Migration Guide](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html) and the [Classic vs Phoenix](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html) documentation page for more information about the changes to wxPython

Comment: Thanks! I'll go and check it out.

Comment: If you don't like what you see, you can use Pyside/pyQT, kivy, or Tkinter in Python 3

Comment: Well, the main problem I'm having right now is that I can't seem to install it ... :p There isn't a setup.py file in these snapshots.

Comment: You might have to grab that from trunk: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxPython/Phoenix/trunk

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to this. So I just grab the whole code of setup.py from this trunk you mentioned and just run it?

Comment: I believe so. If it doesn't work, then check out trunk and run it against that

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though ... It requires some modules I do not have.

Comment: You should ask on the wxPython Google group then

Comment: Grab the `wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.0.0-r75338-win32-py3.3.tar.gz`, unpack `wx` directory and put it in `c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages`. That worked for me on Windows. Should be similar on another platforms.

Comment: `ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython`
It's giving me above error.

Answer (score 2):

[ProjectPhoenix](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix) is in development and will allow wxpython to work with python3.
I couln't tell you how long it will be till it is released but i think it can be used already to a certain extent.

[How "stable" is Phoenix](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/phoenix/wxpython-users/LNAJ7JZZwjA/VNQHahKdpmYJ)

[Phoenix status](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/phoenix/wxpython-users/e3skd4uq0Ck/MX7J3zb2WkkJ)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, and I'm just starting GUI. Won't do anything too special yet ;)