# How to use wxPython for Python 3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, wxpython

I installed `wxPython 3.0.1.1`, but I'm unable to `import wx` using `Python 3.4.1`. I am getting the following error:

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

Nevertheless, I can `import wx` if I use `Python 2.7` (the default installation in my `OS X 10.9`):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>>
```

How can I use wxPython for Python 3, and specifically for Python 3.4.1?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the module's location manually to your `sys.path`:
`sys.path.insert("/location/of/wx")`

Here is a more detailed description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path

Comment: @jotrocken How can I do it in such a way it will be permanent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: This is just a workaround, though. So I wont post it as an answer. Refer to the package's distributor if you need a clean solution. Installing it *should* put the packages in the correct location or extend the paths correctly.

Comment: @jotrocken thanks, the problem is I don't know the correct location where to install wx for python 3. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Default should work, if it is supposed to support Python 3. But it's not. See my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two different pythons installed on your machine (3.4.1 and 2.7.5). Do not expect to be able to use one package installed in one python (wxPython 3.0.1.1 at python 2.7.5) automatically to be available in another python.

Additionally wxPython (classic) does not work for Python 3. You need [*wxPython Phoenix*](http://pythonhosted.org/wxPython/main.html) to be able to do that.

**EDIT**: The recommended way (by @RobinDunn) to install `wxPython` (the Phoenix variety which will work on 2.7 and 3, [now hosted on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython)) nowadays is just doing:

```
pip install wxPython
```

If you have the developer version installed, just do the following beforehand:

```
pip uninstall wxPython_Phoenix
```

You can try to install one of [the wxPython Phoenix snapshots](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/) in your Python 3.4.1. However, mind that Phoenix is not 1000% compatible with classic and you may experience the one or another hiccup when reusing classic code ([but transitioning its doable](http://pythonhosted.org/wxPython/MigrationGuide.html) and worth it).

You can find a complete explanation/description in the following wxPython wiki at the following link:

> [Installing wxPython-Phoenix using pip](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip)

There are several important points:

- that `pip`/`setuptool` is new enough (> 6.x.x/> 12.x.x)
- that the builds are "inofficial", and thus `pip` refuses to install it: basically you need to add `--pre` when installing with pip.
- that you waive SSL verification `--trusted-host wxpython.org` (no longer needed in modern versions where https now works properly).

Full command for Windows machines:

```
C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Note that this will install wxPython Phoenix for Python 2.7.

Comment: To add a bit more to @nepix32's answer, Phoenix's core widgets are ported, but not all the custom widgets are. If you want to use wxPython's core functionality, then Phoenix should work for you.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Can you give me any reference about Phoenix development status?

Comment: Sure. You can check out http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix. I would also recommend looking through the wxPython-dev Google group.

Comment: In addition, there are builds of Phoenix on PyPI now, so a simple `pip install wxPython` will work. There are binaries for Windows and OSX, and pip will attempt to build from source on the other platforms. The snapshots folder is still used for upto daily builds when new commits are checked in to git, but the PyPI releases will be a little more stable and tested.

Answer (score 7):

To use wxPython with your Python 3.4x you need to use wxPython Phoenix - as others have pointed out.  To install it you can do:

```
pip install -U --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Note the space after the last '/' and wxPython_Phoenix

Comment: You get a warning if you use the `http` version instead of the `https` one.

Comment: giving ERROR: No matching distribution found for wxPython_Phoenix

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, wxPython is not yet completely ported for Python 3, even though the version number might suggest that. This is why the wx modules aren't added to the `sys.path` of Python 3.

You can either settle for using wxPython from Python 2.7 or have a look at this SO entry: [Still no wxPython for Python 3 (or 3.3) yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614409/still-no-wxpython-for-python-3-or-3-3-yet) 
This is what @nepix32 suggested.

Alternatively, use another GUI library which works with Python 3. Here is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html#what-platform-independent-gui-toolkits-exist-for-python).

Comment: wxPython 3.x has nothing to do with Python's naming conventions. It is following wxWidgets version numbering scheme. Also, the Phoenix port of wxPython does support Python 3, but it's not a complete port at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sys.path in an interpreter :

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If you don't have the proper link to the proper directory, it won't work.

Also, check Lib/site-packages in your python directory, to make sure wx is properly installed on your python 3. (there should be a directory starting with "wx-3.0")

Comment: I don't know what is the proper link to the proper directory.

Comment: Do you know your Python directory?

Check that directory, go into Lib, then into site-packages. There should be a directory that starts with "wx-3.0".

That's the one you're looking for. Is it in your sys.path?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solutions given earlier worked before. But what worked for me today (June 1, 2017) was:

```
pip install - U - - pre - f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython
```

Always check the Readme.txt for this one...